# Aligning vertical or horizontal grids with percentage in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a `winforms` `User Control` . There are several `grid`s on it. Some of them are horizontally aligned and some of them are vertically aligned.
I'm embedding the `User Control` in a `Form` and i'm setting

```
  this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

On the run, i want the grids to be scaled `horizontally` or `vertically` when fulscreen or minimized screen but i see the absolute heights and widths of grids. For example in minimized screen only the grid on the left is visible and when I make `fulscreen` I see the right grid.(the same for above and below grids)

How can I make them to be scaled relatively whatever the ecreen size is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could separate the grids with SplitContainers(Just nest as much of them as you need). Set FixedPanel to None so that the panels in the splitcontainer are sized relatively to each other. Set IsSplitterFixed to true to prohibit manual resizing. When you anchor your grids to all sides or set DockStyle to Fill you should get what you want.